# Default launcher package name android

Tags: android-intent

I am facing the problem of getting the default launcher package name.

Here is the Manifest file:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.lc.Activity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name="com.lc.StartLockScreen"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I have tried:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.HOME");
ResolveInfo resolveInfo = getPackageManager().resolveActivity(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
String currentHomePackage = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
```

When I put launcher selection code from manifest in comment I get required package name
but on removal of comment I am getting only "android" as package name.
Why is it happening? Please give a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,Because default home screen is part of android System.If you want to access its home screen then use Component class.